# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError running Selenium Chromedriver script

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a simple script in java that opens up URL "http://www.google.com" in a MacBook Pro.  I am using IntelliJ IDEA with Selenium WebDriver + chromedriver.exe System property.

**Code as follows:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

   class Scratch {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/cesarsanchezruiz/Documents/chromedriver");
          WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          try {
              driver.get("http://www.google.com");
          }catch (Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }finally {
             driver.quit();
          }
           }
   }
```

**Intelli J console output (Exception strack trace):**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/asynchttpclient/DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.(NettyClient.java:41)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient$Factory.createClient(NettyClient.java:107)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createClient(HttpClient.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:90)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:73)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.(DriverCommandExecutor.java:67)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.(ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:163)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:150)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:105)
at Scratch.main(scratch.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 11 more
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient$Factory.callAsyncClientShutdown(NettyClient.java:94)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Process finished with exit code 1